# How can I register a structured exception handler in assembly on x86-64 architecture on Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, seh

In x86 you can simply register your handler with the following 3 instructions.

```
push addrOfExceptionHandler
push dword [fs:0]
mov [fs:0],esp
```

But this doesn't work on 64 bit Windows.

I have read the x64 exception handler is table based and Visual C++'s `__try` and `__except` blocks are hard wired into the exception directory. Does this mean the Microsoft totally dropped this old method? Is there a way to register handlers programatically from code then?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the [AddVectoredExceptionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274.aspx) function?

Comment: Yes, that's gone, it was too exploitable by malware.  SAFESEH is a big topic, find help by googling "ml64 exception handling".

Answer (score 3):

Windows x64 uses table-based exception handling (unlike x86 where frame-based handling is used).

Every image has a table of `RUNTIME_FUNCTION` structures associated with it (typically generated by compiler). The structure basically describes a function (or its part) in image and contains information about how to unwind stack in that function. It may also contain information about exception handler that should be called within the function.
When an exception occurs system finds a table that belongs to the image where  exception occurred and uses the table to walk/unwind stack until it hits exception handler that could handle the exception.

This means you cannot use `[fs:0]` for exception handler registration anymore.

Though it is possible to generate `RUNTIME_FUNCTION` tables for loaded/generated image and then register it via `RtlAddFunctionTable` or `RtlInstallFunctionTableCallback` API.

You can find good articles about Windows x64 exception handling at [Nynaeve's blog](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=99).
Also MSDN contains and article about structures used for [Exception Handling (x64)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1eyas8tf.aspx).

Comment: Exception handling is optional, so not every image as a table of RUNTIME_FUNCTION (i.e. .pdata section).